# Count unique values from columnA if adjacent columnB meets a criteria and is not equal to a second criteria

Tags: excel, frequency, countif

This is my first post and hopefully I can explain this issue clearly.

Assuming the following raw excel table:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC             
1       W       A               
1       E       A               
1       W       B               
1       E       C               
1       E       D               
1       E       E               
1       W       E               
1       E       F               


Count of unique E in ColumnB    5               
Count of unique W in ColumnB    3
```

Task:

1) In counting unique values in ColumnC, count unique values that have a value of E in ColumnB.

2) In counting unique values in ColumnC, count unique values that have a value of W in ColumnB, taking into consideration that if an item in ColumnC has both E and W in ColumnB, it should only be counted for assumption 1 above.  Only items in ColumnC that have only W in ColumnB should be included in this count.

As shown in my results, the count for items that have E in ColumnB is 5 which is correct. However, the count for items that have W in ColumnB is returning 3, but it should only return 1 because {1, W, B} is the only row where ColumnC item B has only a W in ColumnB.

The excel formula I have used for both counts are below:

**Count for E**

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$9="1",IF($B$2:$B$9="E",MATCH($C$2:$C$9,$C$2:$C$9,0))),ROW($C$2:$C$9)-ROW($C$2)+1),1))
```

**Count for W**

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$9="1",IF($B$2:$B$9="W",MATCH($C$2:$C$9,$C$2:$C$9,0))),ROW($C$2:$C$9)-ROW($C$2)+1),1))
```

**Note** the formula needs to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

How can I count for W and exclude rows from ColumnC that have both E and W in ColumnB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$9="1",IF($B$2:$B$9="W",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,1,$B$2:$B$9,"E",$C$2:$C$9,$C$2:$C$9)=0,MATCH($C$2:$C$9,$C$2:$C$9,0)))),ROW($C$2:$C$9)-ROW($C$2)+1),1))`

also using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The additional `COUNTIFS` function gives you the extra functionality you need because that checks if there are additional rows with "E" against the relevant column C values

...or an alternative approach would be to count all different values from column C (assuming 1 in column A), and just subtract your "Count for E", so if that "Count for E" formula is in `B12` use this array formula

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$9="1",MATCH($C$2:$C$9,$C$2:$C$9,0)),ROW($C$2:$C$9)-ROW($C$2)+1),1))-B12`

Comment: Thanks so much Barry, perfect solution. I just couldn't get my head around where to insert a statement to check for "count for E" when checking for "count for W".  Thanks, both solutions produce the expected result and I prefer the first because sometimes I may not initially have a "count for E" so there would be noting to subtract.